# Abnormal query execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm execution the same query in two different environments

- The first environment has 4GB RAM and an Intel processor 3,09 Ghz.
- The second environment has 32GB RAM and an AMD processor 2,20 Ghz.

I'm wondering why the query is taking 6 minutes to be executed in the first environment and many many hours in the second one.

I checked the momory allocated for sql server by exectuting the query below, the two environments have the same value.

```
SELECT value_in_use
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'max server memory (MB)'
```

What could be the reason why the query is taking too much time in the second environment?

PS : The number of rows is the same in both environments (about 2 millions)

Comment: query time is also dependent on number of rows in the accessing table. does second environment has big tables?

Comment: Actually the number of rows are the same in both environments..

Comment: check schema difference to see if there is any index missing

Comment: have you compared the query execution plans?

Comment: Could be any number things. Are they the same version of sql server? Are the statistics stale in the second environment? Fragmented indexes? Check the execution plans in both and see what is different.

Comment: Already done, nothing's missing :(

Comment: What about field type, like varchar(50) on the 1st server, and nvarchar(max) on the other one?

Comment: Please post the execution plan for both queries.  Try running another query on both servers.  Does it also perform significantly slower on server2?

Comment: How many cores does each processor have?

Comment: What's the I/O subsystem on the machines like? First machine has SSD, second uses a (badly) configured SAN? There are an infinite number of reasons they could perform differently...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several factors can make the results different. I hesitate to mention them because they are the kind of things people tend to reject, but I have experienced them all and had some confirmed by msft.

First, the person who suggested you look at execution plans is on the right track. That is likely to at least give you a clue as to what's different.

Reasons (assuming size and content of data are identical)

1. Statistics are different on the two servers, causing different execution plans.
2. Hardware performance is different. Slower or faster CPUs (different generation for example, even if clock speed is close), slower or faster disk. More cores vs. one core (leads to parallel plans vs. serial plans)
3. Hardware configuration is different (e.g. perormance difference). One uses a SAN one has direct storage. Sometimes matters a lot. Sometimes makes no difference once data is in cache.
4. Data storage is physically different. One server has greatly fragmented and sparse data blocks/pages in the table(s) or indexes you care about. One has compact and fast. This can occur due to different scenarios used to load data in the two systems.
5. SQLServer configuration settings: Limited Memory configuration on one system, for example.
6. Competing workload on one of the systems.
7. Missing or different indexes.
8. Different collation settings resulting in different index statistics and different plans.
9. Slightly different software version.
10. Size of data is about the same but content is different, changing query plan.

etc.

The time difference involved suggests a different execution plan is most likely.

If all else (indexes, etc.) is 'the same', sometimes it is worth forcing SQLServer to rerun statistics, then try the query again. Historically SQLServer has automatically updated statistics based on the volume of changes to data in a table. Sometimes this leads to statistics that are temporarily bad, as one table hits the threshold for an update but other tables do not, and the optimizer chooses bad plans. It all seems very improbable, but I once built a product that hit this problem regularly, and was fortunate enough to have a visiting MSFT SQLServer developer help me prove it.

Another that has really hit me is slow san or slow VMWare environment. Sans are often claimed to be fast, but turn out to deliver terrible performance to actual users due to slow network connections or competing workloads. VMWare or other virtualization environment often leads to the same problem, especially in large organizations that don't want to figure out what workload is hitting their clusters. Someone else's workload affects yours. So performance testing loses meaning.

My money is on some factor that changes the plan, like data content, statistics, index configuration.

Comment: SANs and Virtualized Databases are some of the most misconfigured things everywhere. I/O is the most important thing to a database but often just left to "those storage guys gave me 100gb disk".

Comment: @NWest You got that right.

Comment: @joshp thanks for the list! Actually the executions plans are similar BUT the cost values are different..